# New Project Debug Dialog in Visual Studio 2022--Why and How It Changed?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I have a .NET 4.8 C# WinForms project loaded in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022. The **Debug** section of the project properties page (right-click the project in Solution Explorer and choose Properties...) looks something like this:

[image]

Notice that there is a clear **Start action** section.

I have another .NET 4.8 C# WinForms project loaded in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022. The **Debug** section of this project properties dialog looks something like this:

[image]

Notice that the Debug General section now states:

> The management of launch profiles has moved to a dedicated dialog. It
> may be accessed via the link below, via the Debug menu in the menu
> bar, or via the Debug Target command on the Standard tool bar.

Other posters here and elsewhere on the web have concluded that (a) the new (latter) dialog is due to Visual Studio 2022 (it is *not*, as both sampled above appeared in Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise; or (b) that this occurs for only projects that are .NET Core projects (that's not true either--both projects above are WinForms 4.8 projects). So if it's not Visual Studio 2022, and it's not .NET Core--then what is it? What causes the former Debug property page to be replaced with the new "dedicated dialog" version?

Moreover, how do you set a **StartAction** when **StartAction** no longer appears on the Debug dialog?

[P.S. Please don't reprimand me for posting screen images--they serve a very clear purpose here and I included the searchable text that appears on those dialog boxes in my question so that this post can be found by others who encounter a similar issue...]

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/709798/where-is-debug-start-action-options-in-a-c-dll-pro) related post might be helpful. It recommends to create an executable profile from within the newly designed Debug dialog.

Comment: @Jazimov Could you share the `.csproj` file of both projects? Whatever is the reason, is there in the `.csproj`.

Comment: Never mind, I reproduced the issue, the one which doesn't show the debug settings is a SDK style project.

Comment: Reza, thank you as always. I saw from the link @Axel Kemper posted that if you choose >=.NET 5 project  template then you'll get the new SDK-style project format. The WinForms project I have has been in use since .NET 4.5--long before .NET 5 was available. I wonder what I did to "convert it" from MSBuild format to SDK format (because I did so unwittingly)?? Is there a process to convert MSBuld format to SDK format? What about from SDK format to MSBuild format??

Comment: This is how you can upgrade from MSBuild To SDK: [How to migrate a Windows Forms desktop app to .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-6.0&preserve-view=true&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#project-file)

Comment: You can also use [Upgrade a Windows Forms App to .NET 6 with the .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-winforms-framework?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: I don't know a tool that helps you to downgrade from a .NET 5+ to 4.8, but I've shared the following guideline for a downgrade (but it uses SDK style for 4.8 as well): [How to roll back solution from .net6 to Framework 4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/955732/how-to-roll-back-solution-from-net6-to-framework-4?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: But I have no idea how you have a .NET 4.x SDK style project ... if the project is on source control you can figure it out by checking the history of the project file.

Comment: So this post is about the changes from MSBuild project files to SDK project files--and also a bit of a detective story about how a 4.8 project has a 5.0+ style project file...! Yes, the project is under source control. I'll check Git and I'll post here if I find out. Meanwhile, there is good information here that I hope serves others well. Thank you ever so much. 

Comment: I guess it has happened at the time of creation. Probably in a VS version, the default WinForms template for .NET 4.X used to use SDK format. But VS 2022 it's using MSBuild format. That would be great if you share your findings on how your .NET 4.X project is using SDK format;  

Comment: Apologies for not being able to follow up sooner: I finally spoke to the developer who made the project-file changes (he was out on leave until now), and he said that he manually modified the project file from the MSBuild format to the SDK format. There was never any sort of automated process--he just eye-balled it to get it right, he said. At least that solves the mystery!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How/why does it show different project property pages for two .NET 4.8 projects?**

It's about the project format:

- The project files with MSBuild project format will use the old Debug settings window.
- The project files with SDK project format will use the new Debug settings window.

**How to set StartAction for SDK style projects?**

In project properties, go to Debug section, General, and click on "Open debug launch profiles UI".

- You can specify command line arguments for the current debug profile.
- Or you can create a new profile (Executable) and specify the executable if you want (like specifying VS, when you want to debug design time of VS).

After you created the new profile, you can just choose it from debug toolbar dropdown button and start that profile.

---

Rest of the answer is just for people who want to see the difference between project format, and also see those new project debug settings.

**MSBuild Project format**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{DE16D3B5-E02E-44A1-B223-2C25ED3F14D9}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>WindowsFormsApp1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WindowsFormsApp1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**SDK Project format**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System" />
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data" />
        <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
        <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
        <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
        <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]